# Illegal operation - should I throw an exception?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

My JEE 7 application consists of two entities (for now): `Owner` and `Company`. I've created also `OwnerService` which contains methods like `boolean ownerHasCompany(Owner, Company)` and `void removeCompanyOfOwner(Owner, Company)`. I'm confused about what should I do when the `Company` does not belong to the `Owner`. I have two ideas:

- Use `ownerHasCompany` method inside `removeCompanyOfOwner` and when it returns `false` then throw an exception (but which? `IllegalArgumentException`?). But in order to avoid this exception client would be obligated to use `ownerHasCompany` method in his code. So the same method would be executed two times.
- Don't check if the `Owner` has the `Company` and leave that only for client. (But I'd like to have logic in Services and only call proper method in my controllers).

Which way would be better? Or maybe there is another solution?

Comment: Option #1 is the way to go. The client should be able to somehow figure out what data it wants to pass to the service in a meaningful way. Hence, in most cases the data will be consistent and a "late" validation inside the service is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using APIs where there is a method for testing when another method will throw an exception. So I think the code for the client should be:

```
if (ownerHasCompany(owner, company)) {
    removeCompanyOfOwner(owner, company);
}
```

The method `removeCompanyOfOwner` could begin with

```
if (!ownerHasCompany(owner, company))
    throw new IllegalStateException();
```

Yes, this means that the method `ownerHasCompany` is called twice. I don't know how this check is done, but it seems likely that this inefficiency is insignificant.

An alternative is to make `removeCompanyOfOwner` return a `boolean`; `true` if the company was removed, `false` otherwise. With this solution the method `removeCompanyOfOwner` begins

```
if (!ownerHasCompany(owner, company))
    return false;
```

Comment: "Huh. Company was not removed?! But why? Did it not exist? Or did the owner not exist? Or did they both exist but not together?" - I prefer throwing the exception to make that clear to the caller.

Comment: I also think that exception is a good way so I'll do that in this way. Thanks.

Comment: @HannoBinder I prefer the exception solution too, but the `boolean` return value is consistent with `Collection.remove`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Yes it is. But that's because the generic collection cannot make any asumption upon whether or not the business logic of the application requires to only (try to) remove existing elements or not. Thus, an exception would be out of place for the collection, IMHO.

Comment: @HannoBinder I agree with you. My answer says that I think the exception solution is the best one. My point about the `boolean` solution was just that it wasn't totally ridiculous.